# Run MySql with docker-compose; login error: "The server requested authentication method unknown to the client"

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I need to run MySql docker container. Following the instructions on MySql official Docker repository (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/), I did the following steps:

Step 1. I composed stack.yml file as the following, then run: **docker-compose -f stack.yml up**

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Step 2. Browse to http://localhost:8080/

A login form is display. It says:

System: MySql

Server: db

Then I input **root** as Username and **example** as Password, and leave Database textbox empty, then click **Login**.
It displays error: 
"**SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client**"

Any hint/clue on how to fix this will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

=========

The following is from the terminal:

docker-compose -f stack.yml up

```
Starting hibernate_db_1      ... done
Starting hibernate_adminer_1 ... done
Attaching to hibernate_db_1, hibernate_adminer_1
db_1       | 2018-05-23T07:34:08.186378Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
db_1       | 2018-05-23T07:34:08.186678Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.11) starting as process 1
db_1       | mbind: Operation not permitted
db_1       | mbind: Operation not permitted
adminer_1  | PHP 7.2.5 Development Server started at Wed May 23 07:34:08 2018
db_1       | 2018-05-23T07:34:09.011741Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting crash recovery...
db_1       | 2018-05-23T07:34:09.012443Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] Crash recovery finished.
db_1       | 2018-05-23T07:34:09.214122Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db_1       | 2018-05-23T07:34:09.226905Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db_1       | 2018-05-23T07:34:09.255716Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.infoschema@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1       | 2018-05-23T07:34:09.256491Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1       | 2018-05-23T07:34:09.256797Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1       | 2018-05-23T07:34:09.257188Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1       | 2018-05-23T07:34:09.257654Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010323] [Server] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1       | 2018-05-23T07:34:09.258015Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010323] [Server] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1       | 2018-05-23T07:34:09.258420Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010311] [Server] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1       | 2018-05-23T07:34:09.273119Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010330] [Server] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1       | 2018-05-23T07:34:09.273798Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010330] [Server] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1       | 2018-05-23T07:34:09.299367Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.11'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

When I browser to http://localhost:8080, the terminal prints:

```
adminer_1  | [Wed May 23 07:34:28 2018] ::ffff:172.18.0.1:35388 [200]: /
```

After I click login, the terminal prints:

```
adminer_1  | [Wed May 23 07:34:41 2018] ::ffff:172.18.0.1:35396 [302]: /
adminer_1  | [Wed May 23 07:34:41 2018] ::ffff:172.18.0.1:35398 [403]: /?server=db&username=root
```

Comment: just speculating, can you try logging in with a separate user other than root ?
I faced a similar issue with postgres, I had to create a new user and then login with that user and it worked fine
Or probably some config mess up with adminer ?

Comment: Could you please share your `docker-compose up` logs ?

Comment: Hi fly2matrix, I have updated the op with terminal output. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, skybunk, I have tried with a new username/password, and it was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adminer is compatible with mysql8 using some extension , as available in requirements on home page for adminer. https://www.adminer.org/

> adminer with mysql 4.1, 5.0, 5.1, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 8.0 through extensions: mysql, mysqli, pdo_mysql

So you can revert back to mysql-5.7

```
    version: '3.1'

    services:

      db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        restart: always
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
          MYSQL_USER: user
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass

      adminer:
        image: adminer
        restart: always
        ports:
          - 8080:8080
```

Comment: You are right. It is version issue. When I use mysql 5.7, adminer can login.

Comment: It's not a MySQL version issue. In MySQL 8.0.11, caching_sha2_password is the default authentication plugin rather than mysql_native_password. For information about the implications of this change for server operation and compatibility of the server with clients and connectors, see caching_sha2_password as the Preferred Authentication Plugin - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-caching-sha2-password. Problem is that adminer don't have implemented new authentication method.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with the hashes that are used to store the password. The mysql client used by adminer might not be compatible 
with the newest mysql version.

Try pinning the right versions in the docker-compose.yml and make sure that the adminer container supports the used mysql version. (Important: Even if Adminer supports the latest MySQL Version, the container might use an old MySQL client)

The examples in hub.docker.com for adminer show, that they are pinning mysql to 5.6. You could try to do that to check if your setup works. (https://hub.docker.com/_/adminer/)

Comment: When I pin mysql to 5.6, it works. Thank you very much.